# Separate heavy static page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app which for front-end depends on bootstrap, jquery and lot of jquery plugins.
I want to have a promo page for it using a 3rd party template.It has its own dependencies(lot of them) and i don't want it to mess with rest of my app in any way.
Basically i want it to be as separate as possible from rest of my app.
Its totally static and doesn't need to interact with rest of app.
I don't require even erb for templating.
Also i want it to ave separate set of dependencies from rest of app.
How could i achieve this?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking. Rails is a back-end HTTP server framework, but you seem to be talking about JQuery and other front-end dependencies. What dependencies do you want to isolate, why can't you do it, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create separate, static `index.html` file in the `public` folder of your application and make sure that root doesn't point to any controller action in `config/routes.rb` file.

If you want to serve it on some specific path, other than root, just create those folders inside the `public` folder and put your `index.html` file there.

In that case, it won't mess with rest of your application and you'll benefit because your web server (i.e. nginx) can cache it and serve it much faster than dynamically generated pages.

Comment: and the dependencies do i just keep it in a folder alongside `index.html` in `public` folder?do i need to declare the css and js files in `assets.rb`?How do i link to this page from some controller?@IvanLučev

Comment: You can put these dependencies also in `public` folder, and reference it using same path as it is in the folder (like `css/something.css`, if it is `public/css/something.css`). If you have an action associated to this page, you have to configure it in `routes.rb` (and could put these pages in `views` folder to make it simple to render).

Comment: I would put them alongside index.html in public folder, probably in subfolder like stylesheets and javascripts, as @AndréGuimarãesSakata said. 

Adding them to assets could be useful for precompile and merging them into a single file to avoid multiple requests but your static file won't be aware of a generated md5 hash fingerprint so I'm not sure how that would work and is it possible to configure it somehow.

Comment: these file will be cached to user right?so it is not redownloaded next time user visits?